# Not able to select a table even if having SELECT privilege

Tags: select, oracle10g, sql-grant

I have two users, `USER1` and `USER2`. `USER1` has privilege to `create table` and `USER2` does not have this privilege.

`USER1` has created a table called `EMPLOYEE` and granted the `select` privilege on that table to `USER2`:

====== **Using USER1 credentials** =======

1) Create table-

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
   EMP_ID NUMBER,
   EMP_NAME VARCHAR2 (20 BYTE)
);
```

2) Grant permission to user2

```
GRANT SELECT ON EMPLOYEE TO USER2;
```

====== **Using USER2 credentials** =======

Now I want to access the `EMPLOYEE` table using `USER2` credentials:

```
SELECT * from EMPLOYEE
```

But it is giving error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * from USER1.EMPLOYEE;
```

This might happen if there is no public synonym present for EMPLOYEE table. So you need to refer using the owner.object

If not getting results, please post the results of

```
SELECT
      OWNER,
      TABLE_NAME
FROM
      ALL_TABLES
WHERE
      TABLE_NAME IN ('EMPLOYEE');
```

Comment: Could you please post all your statements right from creating users, tables, grants and select statement WITH their results?

Comment: Please post the output of USING USER2 CREDENTIALS SELECT * from USER1.EMPLOYEE;

Comment: Do you use the statement inside any PL SQL block?

Comment: It worked!!!! I used **owner.object** i.e. `SELECT * from APPSUSER.EMPLOYEE` as suggested by you. Thanks !!!!!!